# How to increase compression speed for FFmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have used following command for compress video in android.

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_20150326_125017.mp4 -strict experimental -s 640x360 -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1000k -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4
```

Above command is a work properly, but it's taking too much time for compression.
An 80MB video file takes around 3 minutes to compress to an 8MB file. Is there any way I can reduce this time.

Comment: possibly use x264 "ultrafast" options, or if you want mp4 video codec, maybe decrease the resolution or some option it allows?

Comment: Thanks rogerdpack for solution. I have already tried "ultrafast" and I want same resolution for compression in above command.

Comment: there may be some trade off between "fast" and "size" https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide has some examples of "fast" encoding, GL!

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
-y -i $sourceFile -s ${width}x${height} -r 5 -c:v libx264 -b:v 600k -b:a 44100 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -tune fastdecode -preset ultrafast $destPath
```

This command uses `libx264` codec and `-r 5`  reduces the time taken.
`-tune fastdecode -preset ultrafast` this is also used for faster compression.

Reference [ffmpeg preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Result :
SOURCE SIZE : 63.7 MB DEST SIZE : 5.06MB
Time Taken : 15 Secs

Answer (score 1):

Try the command mentioned below to compress videos. In my situation, 52 MB of video was compressed to 12 MB in about 19 seconds.

```
function command(input, output, bitrate) {


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
      ffmpeg(input)
        .outputOptions(['-c:v libx264', `-b:v ${bitrate}k`, '-c:a aac', '-b:a 58k','-crf 35'])
        .output(output)
        .on('start', (command) => {
          console.log('TCL: command -> command', command)
        })
        .on('progress', function (progress) {
          console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
        })
        .on('error', (error) => reject(error))
        .on('end', () => resolve())
        .run()
    })
  }
```

Comment: Why Javascript? Original question is a shell cmd...

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command for video compression
In my case, i had video of 82mb and compressed to 5mb within around 50secs.

```
 String[] command = new String[]{"-i", videoPath, "-vcodec", "h264", "-b:v", "1000k", "-acodec", "mp3" ,"-preset", "ultrafast", outputPath};
```

Hope it works!

Comment: getting [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x7e777d5f00] can't configure encoder error.